# How to match two arrays to corresponding user input?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

As I run the code, the final output is Rent for apartment # 204 is `$System.Int32[]`.  My question's focus is in the `getRent` method. When I step into the code, the for loop functions finds the user input `apartmentNumber` then runs through the apartment array to match the index. So when it goes to the `printit` method, it's still showing the user input `apartmentNumber`.

How do I match the corresponding rent index?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] apartment = { 123, 204, 601, 609, 612 }; // initialize apartment array
    int[] rent = {500, 750, 495, 800, 940 }; // intitialize rent array
    int apartmentNumber = 0; // declare apartmentNumber int

    getRent (apartment , rent, apartmentNumber ); /*pass the apartment and rent 
    array by ref and apartment number console entry */

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..."); // Lets user know program over
    Console.ReadKey(); // keeps the program from closing quickly after executing
}

static void getRent(int [] apartment, int [] rent, int apartmentNumber) //method getRent
{ 
    Console.WriteLine ("Enter apartment number"); // query user to enter apartment number
    apartmentNumber = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ()); // convert apartment number to int

    for (int i = 0; i < apartment.Length - 1; i++) // for loop to match apartmentNumber

    if (apartment[i] == apartmentNumber)// match it to apartment array


    Console.WriteLine(); // space between user input and output
    printit(apartmentNumber, rent);
}

static void printit (int apartmentNumber, int [] rent) // static method printit 
{
    string string1 = "Rent for apartment #" + apartmentNumber;
    string string2 = " is $" + rent;

    StringBuilder mystring = new StringBuilder();

    mystring.Append(string1);
    mystring.Append(string2);
    Console.WriteLine(mystring); 
}
```

Comment: Paired arrays like that, where matching indexes correspond to attributes of a single element, is almost always a bad design. Instead, write a class to hold apartment number and rent as members of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, all that your `getRent` method does is to forward the call to `printit` method.
Be aware that the `printit` call in `getRent` is neither part of the `if` code block, nor of the `for` code block.

Moreover, what are you expecting to store in `string2` varaible in method `printit`? You're using the + operator with a string and an array. If this is C#, the string representation of the `rent` array will be concatenated to " is $".

EDIT:
That's what you need: the instruction block inside the following statement:

```
if (apartment[i] == apartmentNumber)// match it to apartment array
```

should be the following:

```
{
    int apartmentRent = rent[i];
    System.out.println("Rent for apartment # " + apartmentNumber + "is $ " + apartmentRent);
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: @ Andrei, What I'm trying to do is get rent in the printit method to correspond to the matching index. So if the user inputs an apartment number of 609, rent should display 800

Comment: I see. You're not quite doing what you should :D What you're doing with the input form your user is just to print a new line when it happens that an element in the `apartment` array is equal to the user input. See my edited answer for a snippet of code that I thing would do what you're exepcting.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using brackets for your `for` loop and `if` statement.

So this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < apartment.Length - 1; i++) // for loop to match apartmentNumber

if (apartment[i] == apartmentNumber)// match it to apartment array

Console.WriteLine(); // space between user input and output
printit(apartmentNumber, rent);
```

Is actually doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < apartment.Length - 1; i++) // for loop to match apartmentNumber
{
    if (apartment[i] == apartmentNumber)// match it to apartment array
    {
        Console.WriteLine(); // space between user input and output
    }
}
printit(apartmentNumber, rent);
```

So you can see that the call to `printit` is outside both the loop and if statement.

It's good practice to use brackets even for single statements as:

1. It makes it easier to spot problems like this.
2. It makes it easier to add code to the right place in loops and if statements should you need to at a later date.

Also your `printit` function is taking `rent` as an array when it should probably be just an int (though you should be using a floating point type here):

```
static void printit (int apartmentNumber, int rent)
{
     ....
}
```

Then the body of the method makes sense.

The call to it then becomes:

```
printit(apartmentNumber, rent[i]);
```

as that will be inside the loop.

Comment: that's a good point about the printit Method. I didn't think about having rent as a float or int type. Thanks!